# Empty output when creating QTiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, tile-map-service

I am trying to follow the directions to create a base map with QTiles in QGIS. Here is the link with instructions for reference: https://astuntechnology.github.io/qgis-tutorials/html/en/docs/creating_basemaps_with_qtiles.html

When I create the QTiles and then click on *'QTILES1.html'*, I get the following result.

[image]

I have tried to change the CRS, but it does not help. You can see the errors in the image below next to the blank screen.

Any suggestions?

I am using QGIS 3.28 Firenze on a Macbook 14 Pro 2022.

Comment: Can you please show us the settings of your QTiles export dialog?

Comment: BTW, are you working with *'QTILES.html'* or  *'QTILES1.html'*?